# 'Drama is hard for me' - Grammar

Tags: syntax

What are the parts in this sentence?

> Drama is hard for me.

My thoughts so far:

"Drama" is the subject

"Is" is the verb

"Hard" is the predicate complement?

"Me" is the indirect object?

Not really sure about the last two, so can someone please clarify?

Comment: Right for subject, verb, and predicate complement. *Me* is the object of the preposition *for*.

Comment: 'For me' is an Adjunct. (Some people use the term Adverbial).